# Calling php file on wordpress page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, api

I have a php file which contains functions that connects with API. Functions in that file work correctly when tested from another php file. Website that should call this functions is written using wordpress. Since I'm not familiar with wordpress, how could I call them?
For example:
Website have login form which contains one button. On button click I also have to call my function which is implemented in external (self written) php file. 
I do know that button click is on client side and php is on server side. What bugs me is that when I saw source code of website I've seen that all pages are written in php but I can't navigate through them.
What would be the easyest way to call this function on those button clicks?

Comment: When the user clicks the button on the login page, it has to call an HTTP endpoint. You need to hook into this and direct it to the function you want to run. I do not believe that you can add to the login page using wordpress registration functions for security reasons, however you can add a route to your endpoint with the register_rest_route function. You would have to modify your login.php file to add the button, which would be most likely wiped each time you update your wordpress. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/

Comment: @Nemanja Cvijan: Please check my answer and reply your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can include file like this:

you can load this file in `current theme function.php`

```
get_template_part('filename');
```

filename means your php file name.

add php file in your theme file.

Comment: I'm not home so I cant try it out. When I include my file into functions.php how do I call them on click event when I cant find that button but I know his id/class?

Comment: You can add html part in  your wordpress theme and add custom php function parts  in function.php